# Object id of item returned by index() appears wrong

Tags: list, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 and have an ordered list of objects (in self.root.content) that I'm querying using the index method. However, the value of the index returned by 'index' apparently does not match the index of the object that I want (held in my_obj).
If I 'manually' loop over the list and look for my object:

```
    for idx,body in enumerate(self.root.content):
        print idx,id(body),": ", body
        if body is my_obj:
            print "Match at index {0}".format(idx)
```

Then I get the following output:

```
  ...
  12 64788560 :        REAL(KIND=wp), intent(inout) :: rdt
  13 64788880 :        INTEGER, intent(inout) :: istp
  14 64717648 :        INTEGER j
  15 36601744 :        INTEGER i
  16 36599504 :        INTEGER istop, jstop
  Match at index 16
  17 36599952 :        DO j=2,jstop
  ...
```

However, if I use the built-in index method like so:

```
    my_index = self.root.content.index(my_obj) 
    print "ID for object at returned index ({0}) is: {1}".\
        format(my_index, id(self.root.content[my_index]))
```

Then I get:

```
   ID for object at returned index (13) is: 64788880
```

I'm at a loss to explain this. Can anyone shed any light? (I've checked the type() of self.root.content and it is 'list'.)

Thanks to Kevin's suggestion I tried:

```
    for idx,body in enumerate(self.root.content):
        print idx,id(body),": ", body
        if body == my_obj:
            print "Match at index {0}".format(idx)
```

and that gave:

```
...
13 48174928 :        INTEGER, intent(inout) :: istp
Match at index 13
14 48099600 :        INTEGER j
Match at index 14
15 48095184 :        INTEGER i
Match at index 15
16 48092944 :        INTEGER istop, jstop
Match at index 16
...
```

I was under the impression that the index method returned the index in the list of the supplied object. If this is not the case then what does it match on for an arbitrary/complex object?

Comment: One possible difference: `is` checks for identical identity, and `index` only checks for equality. Does your first code act the same if you change `if body is my_obj` to `if body == my_obj`?

Comment: What does your first code print for the the 13th `idx`?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I've figured it out:
Some (but not all) of the objects in the list belong to a class that has overridden the **eq** operator and that has changed the default behaviour of the test for equality. Presumably the index() method tests for equality rather than using 'is'.
I think I'll have to do the look-up manually using the 'is' test as I did in my first code fragment in the question.